# How to limit the accessibility of an abstract class to another abstract class and its subclasses?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, access-modifiers

Given two abstract classes A and B, how to make the public member function of A only accessible to B and its derived classes? i.e.

```
class A {
public:
   virtual ~A(){}
   virtual void foo() = 0; // foo only accessible to B and its subclasses; foo is private to others
};
class B {
   virtual ~B(){}
   virtual void goo() = 0;
};
```

Comment: You can't if you want to keep it public.  Public means everyone has access.

Comment: You may use protected function and inheritance or friend functions.

Comment: Make class `B` inherit `A` ( `class B : public A` ) then we will be able to define foo in B or any of its subclasses.

Comment: All of your accessibility restrictions can be disabled with `#define private public` and `#define class struct` if someone is so inclined.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `A::foo` private (or protected). If it is public, then there are no limits on access.

Only way to give access to a non-public function to unrelated class is to declare the class a friend.

Friendliness is not inherited however. So, `B` needs to provide protected function that delegates to the restricted function so that derived classes can access the member through `B`.

An example:

```
class A {
   ...
   friend class B;
private:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B {
   ...
protected:
    void foo(A& a) {
        a.foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: If they make it private the name is not available to the derived classes.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's infeasible for `A` to list the derived classes of `B` as friends. That's why the derived classes need to access the function through the helper in base.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overengineered, but here's my suggestion.

TL;DR: Make `goo()` public and add a dummy parameter to it that can only be constructed by `B` or classes derived from it.

---

First, you create a dummy class (let's say `AccessKey<T>`) that can only be constructed by `T` (the constructor is private and `T` is a `friend`).

Additionally, `AccessKey<T>` should be convertible to `AccessKey<U>` if `U` is a base of `T`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class AccessKey
{
    friend T;
    template <typename> friend class AccessKey;

    constexpr AccessKey() {}

  public:
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
    constexpr operator AccessKey<U>() const {return {};}
};
```

Then you make `virtual void foo() = 0` public, and add a `AccessKey<B>` parameter (forward-declare `class B` first).

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual void foo(AccessKey<B>) = 0;
};
```

Then...

```
class B
{
  public:
    void goo(A &a)
    {
        a.foo(AccessKey<B>{}); // ok
    }
};

class C : public B
{
  public:
    void goo(A &a)
    {
        a.foo(AccessKey<C>{}); // ok
    }
};

class D
{
  public:
    void goo(A &a)
    {
        a.foo(AccessKey<D>{}); // error: AccessKey<D> is not convertible to AccessKey<B>
        a.foo(AccessKey<B>{}); // error: AccessKey<B>() is private
    }
};
```